# how to make status badge in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

does someone already make a such kind of packages like github readme：

​[image: ​Build Status​]
​[image: ​Quality Gate Status​]

if no，how to make a such kind of badges in tcolorbox！

Answer (score 6):

Here is something for you to get start with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand \GitHubBadge { m m m }
  {
    \tcbsidebyside
      [
        enhanced, sidebyside, sidebyside adapt=both,
        bicolor, colback=black, colbacklower=green!70!black,
        frame hidden,
        left=2pt, right=2pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
        sidebyside gap=1em,
      ]
    {\sffamily\textcolor{gray}{#1}~\textcolor{white}{#2}\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{q}}
    {\sffamily\hspace{-1.5em}\phantom{#1}\textcolor{white}{#3}\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{q}}
  }

\begin{document}

\GitHubBadge { \faIcon{github} } { Build } { passing }

\end{document}
```

The `\phantom`s are for the vertical alignment of the text on two sides.

[image]

---

Below is a version with text shadow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{shadowtext}

\NewDocumentCommand \GitHubBadge { m m m }
  {
    \shadowoffsetx{0pt}
    \shadowoffsety{0.6pt}
    \tcbsidebyside
      [
        enhanced, sidebyside, sidebyside adapt=both,
        bicolor, colback=black, colbacklower=green!70!black,
        frame hidden,
        left=2pt, right=2pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, boxsep=1.5pt,
        sidebyside gap=0em,
      ]
    {\shadowcolor{black!80}\sffamily\textcolor{gray}{#1}\!\textcolor{white}{\shadowtext{#2}}\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{q}}
    {\shadowcolor{black!60}\sffamily\hspace{-1.5em}\phantom{#1}\textcolor{white}{\shadowtext{#3}}\hspace{-1em}\phantom{q}}
  }

\begin{document}

\GitHubBadge { \faIcon{github} } { Build } { passing }

\end{document}
```

[image]